# How to create database and use it in wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress

i  am newbie to wordpress.I just created a  free blog in Wordpress.I want  to know  how  to create Database in it and  use it. Any  links to  good tutorial will  be  great.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress itself uses a  MySQL database to store (among other things) post content and meta, users, info about plugins, etc.

In terms of creating a separate database from the one that's in WordPress itself, the question you're asking itself makes me very hesitant to think that you should. You'd be dealing with passwords, permissions, and a whole range of very easy to screw up settings that probably aren't worth playing with if you're new to WordPress.

If you wanted to use the database in WordPress itself and have the ability to write queries or create tables, you could look at any number of SQL plugins (eg http://wordpress.org/plugins/sql-executioner/ or https://wordpress.org/plugins/elisqlreports/) that would allow you to query tables in the WordPress database.... I don't recall if the existing plugins would allow you to create/modify tables, but phpMyAdmin or terminal would be just fine for that if not.

Since you're new, let me *****strongly***** encourage you not to modify/delete the default tables in WordPress, especially not on a live site.

Best of luck

Comment: My Dashboard does not have plugin option..i am using wordpress.com

Comment: are you on wordpress.com?

Comment: Yes  i am using wordpress.com

Comment: The short answer is "you can't." The slightly longer answer is you really need to go learn more about WordPress.org vs WordPress.com.